# Meaning of 'flirt' in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know that 'flirt' usually means, but I think here that word has a different meaning. I guess the sentences below seem to mean that the blue-jay tried to see where the acorn was disappearing. 
Here is the example, which is from a novel 'Baker's blue-jay yarn' by Mark Twain.

*So he flew off and fetched another acorn and dropped it in, and tried to* ***flirt*** *his eye to the hole quick enough to see what become of it, but he was too late.*

Answer (score 1):

If you type "flirt meaning" into Google, it returns the following:

> flirt
>
> fləːt/
>
> verb
>
> 1. behave as though sexually attracted to someone, but playfully rather than with serious intentions.
> 2. (of a bird) wave or open and shut (its wings or tail) with a quick flicking motion.

You would want the second definition in this case.

> So he flew off and fetched another acorn and dropped it in and tried to quickly flick his yes to the hole ...

In case you don't know what flick means in this case Google returns this as one of the definitions:

> noun
>
> 1. a sudden quick movement.